# Socket not defined error in client application

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI for this script I made. I want to press the *connect* button first to connect to the server. then hit *send* to send a file. But when I press connect it sends an empty text file and the send button gives me an error that my socket is not defined.

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):

def __init__(self, master):

    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets()

def create_widgets(self):

    self.instruction = Label(self, text = 'Enter ip')
    self.instruction.grid(row=0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

    self.instruction = Label(self, text = 'Enter Port')
    self.instruction.grid(row=1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

    self.instruction = Label(self, text = '      ')
    self.instruction.grid(row=2, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

    self.instruction = Label(self, text = 'Enter path')
    self.instruction.grid(row=5, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

    self.ip = Entry(self)
    self.ip.grid(row=0, column = 1, sticky = W)

    self.port = Entry(self)
    self.port.grid(row=1, column = 1, sticky = W)

    self.path = Entry(self)
    self.path.grid(row=5, column = 1, sticky = W)

    self.submit_button = Button(self, text='connect', command = self.connect)
    self.submit_button.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = W)

    self.send_button = Button(self, text='Send file', command = self.send)
    self.send_button.grid(row = 5, column = 2, sticky = W)

    self.text = Text(self, width = 80, height = 5, wrap = WORD)
    self.text.grid(row = 10, column = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = W)

def connect(self):

    ip = self.ip.get()
    port = int(self.port.get())

    import socket
    import sys
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((ip, port))

    self.text.insert(0.0, 'connecting to' ,ip, port )

def send(self):
    path = self.path.get()
    f=open (path, "rb") 
    l = f.read(1024)
    while (l):
        s.send(l)
        l = f.read(1024)
    s.close()

 root = Tk()
 root.title("Client")
 root.geometry("420x200")
 app = Application(root)

 root.mainloop()
```

this is my server script

```
from Tkinter import *

import socket
import sys

class Application(Frame):

def __init__(self, master):

    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets()

def create_widgets(self):

    self.text = Text(self, width = 35, height = 5, wrap = WORD)
    self.text.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

    self.submit_button = Button(self, text='start', command = self.start)
    self.submit_button.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)

def start(self):

    self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.text.insert(0.0, 'Server started!\n' )
    self.s.bind(('',1080))
    self.s.listen(10)

    while True:
        sc, address = self.s.accept()
        i=1
        f = open('file_'+ str(i)+".txt",'wb') #open in binary
        i=i+1
        while (True):       
            l = sc.recv(1024)
            while (l):
                print l 
                f.write(l) 
                f.flush()
                l = sc.recv(1024)
        f.close()

        sc.close()

    #s.close()


  root = Tk()
  root.title("Server")
  root.geometry("500x250")
  app = Application(root)
  root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Always post the actual error/traceback if you get any.

Comment: Side note: You should put the `import sys` and `import socket` at the top of your module unless you have a very good reason to do otherwise. (Actually, you shouldn't have `import sys` at all, since you  never use it…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s` is a local variable of `connect`, so it isn't within the scope of the `send` method. Since you are already using a class for the application, you can store a reference to the socket by replacing every `s` with `self.s`.

Also keep in mind that your socket operations run on the GUI thread, so your application won't be responsive until they finish their execution. As a possible solution, you can use the [`threading` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) to run them on a separate thread.

Comment: +1. (Also, it might be nice to call it `self.sock` or something, for readability.)

Comment: thanks alot it work fine now but can i ask you about something else i want when i press the connect button t open a new window with the option of sending a file on it howa can i do that

Comment: @MohamedShafie Then you need to create a `Toplevel` widget. You can read more about the use of this class [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm). By the way, feel free to accept this answer if it solved your problem ;)

Comment: ok thanks alot again may i ask another question or i have to do a new post ?

Comment: my problem is with my server script it works fine without th gui but with it when i press the start button it just freezes and say not responding

Comment: @MohamedShafie I've updated my answer. If you have more questions and they are not related with this one, I recommend you to ask them in a separate post.